# Container image support for AWS Lambda via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

AWS Lambda now supports container images as a packaging format. [Ref](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-now-supports-container-images-as-a-packaging-format/)

Does cloudformation support using Container image for deploying AWS Lambda?

Something similar to packaging and deployment support via S3 [Ref](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/deploying-aws-lambda-functions-using-aws-cloudformation-the-portable-way/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does cloudformation support using Container image for deploying AWS Lambda?

Yes it does. [AWS::Lambda::Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-imageconfig) has new properties specific to container images, such as:

- `ImageConfig`
- `PackageType`
- `ImageUri`

Comment: cool did not know this. what are possible use cases for this?

Comment: The OP is @jenson. I upvoted, thanks for the info.

Comment: @RodrigoM Oh. Sorry. Got confused :-)

Comment: @Marcin, One more related question: Does it support registry other than AWS ECR? like Docker hub or private JFrog? Thanks!

Comment: @Jenson Yes, both ECR public and docker hub should work.

Answer (score 6):

@Marcin points to the correct documentation.
@Jenson 's answer relies on AWS SAM.

Here is the pure CloudFormation template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  EcrImageUri:
    Description: ECR image URI
    Type: String
Resources:
  LambdaShogi:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - LambdaShogiRole
        - Arn
      Code:
        ImageUri: !Ref 'EcrImageUri'
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      MemorySize: 1024
      Timeout: 300
  LambdaShogiRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

By passing the image URI, you can deploy the container Lambda function.

```
$ aws cloudformation deploy \
  --stack-name lambda-container-test \
  --template-file ./cfn.yml \
  --parameter-overrides EcrImageUri=<YOUR-ACCOUNT-ID>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/test:latest \
  --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  TestNode12Lambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      FunctionName: testnode12lambda
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - TestNode12LambdaRole
        - Arn
      ImageUri: {aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/lambda-container:latest
      Timeout: 300
  TestNode12LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: TestNode12LambdaRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - logs:CreateLogGroup
            - logs:CreateLogStream
            - logs:PutLogEvents
            Resource: '*'
```

Command to deploy:
`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file resources.yml --stack-name lambdacft --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM`

Sample code to deploy node12 Lambda as container image: https://github.com/jensonjoseph/lambda-cft

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these under your lambda function properties

Properties:
PackageType: Image
ImageUri:  # get it from ECR

Remove code , CodeUri , runtime , layers and handler properties from the yaml file for that lambda function